# access Activities UI component inside fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity

I have an activity where two fragments are attached. 
I am trying to access UI components of Activity.xml, in Fragment.xml.
Also i am trying to hide toolbar in specific fragment. 
But unable to reach at any point.

these are the things i have tried

1. for hide fragment toolbar -
2. for accessing the UI button of activity inside fragment

   ```
   ((DashBoardActivity) getActivity()).addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class));
       }
   });
    //For HIDING TOOLBAR IN FRAGMENT

    (activity as DashboardActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
   ```

Can someone please help me achieving this in KOTLIN.
Thank you

Comment: you can hide toolbar by adding backstackchangelistener and show toolbar from fragment where you wana show/hide or via interface and implement interface in activity, secondly what is the need to access activity UI component in fragment ?

Comment: I have an Imageview which needs to be handled for different cases. That's why i am trying this @Ne

Comment: handle that in activity only and call from fragment via interface only